# SSH jumphost does not execute ForceCommand

Tags: ssh

When I have a "ForceCommand" in my SSHD config, when I directly login to the host, I see the script specified in the "ForceCommand" being executed. However, when I use the host as a Jumphost, I don't see "ForceCommand" being executed, my intention is to write a script to validate if the user can connect to the destination host from a jumphost perspective. Any ideas on how to make a jumphost call a script that can do this?

Answer (score 1):

Using `JumpHost`, there is no shell opened on the server, only the IO forwarding to connect to other hosts. If you need to validate whether the user can connect to the destination host, you should do that earlier, preferably during authentication in pam. `ForceCommand` is too late to check access.

Unfortunately, there is no simple way to see what will be the target of the JumpHost in the server. The client will get socket and it will use it to connect to other hosts.

You might be able to use `permitopen` option or the same `authorized_keys` file option, which should allow you to limit what the connecting client can do (assuming are using public key authentication) or additionally provide this information using `AuthorizedKeysCommand` if you insist on scripts.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I tried AuthorizedKeysCommand approach, I made it work for my own key for now, but in that there is no option of finding the destination server. Like you had indicated, perhaps this is done at a stage where shell is opened, and its late. Is my understanding right?

Any idea how these jumphosts screen recording or RBAC's are done? for example Gravitational's Teleport has it only for the enterprise edition.

Comment: No idea, but they probably don't use JumpHost, but they need to initiate the connection to the remote server themselves (otherwise all what they would see would be encrypted).